# Removing a second viewcontroller's view after dissmissing mail controller

Tags: iphone

A second viewcontroller has mailcontroller and after finishing mail, it post a message to the mainviewcontroller to remove the secondviewcontroller's view. but it's not happening. The mailcontroller appearing and disappearing seem to interferes with finish function of the mainviewcontroller.

secondviewcontroller:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"finish" object:nil];
```

mainviewcontroller:

```
-(void) finish:(NSNotification *)notif {

    [MyviewController.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: Have you registered for the notification OK? Sending a notification named "finish" does not invoke the method called finish automatically...

Comment: Please include code where you show your mailcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The removal of the second view controller should be delayed until your modal controller is really removed. What I have done is following:

```
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  m_shouldHide = YES;
```

And then:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  if ( m_shouldHide )
  {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    m_shouldHide = NO;
  }
}
```

Comment: my "second controller" was also a modal one. So in your case viewDidAppear handler should throw the notification you want. Or without any notification just do the [self.view removeFromSuperView]

Comment: you are right on waiting for the mailcontroller to disappear before doing anything to the 2nd viewcontroller's view.  But I don't think you need another dissmissModalView inside the viewdidappear.

Comment: In my case I need because I have to remove 2 modal view controllers. And it works pretty good in production